# Find properties where parameter not in List<> of nested properties

Tags: winforms, linq

Firstly, I have an enum as

```
internal enum property_name
{
  label = 1
  ,
  from = 2
  ,
  to = 3
  ,
  forwardTo = 4
}
```

Secondly, I have a class that references the enum on the innermost nested class _property

```
internal class cls_xml_filters
{
  internal string title { get; set; }

  internal List<_entry> entry { get; set; }

  internal class _entry
  {
    internal string category { get; set; }

    internal string id { get; set; }

    internal DateTime updated { get; set; }

    internal List<_property> property { get; set; }

    internal class _property
    {
      internal property_name name { get; set; }

      internal string value { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

The _property class can have one or many entries, and _property.name does not always contain all values of enum property_name.

I want to find all the unique _entries.id where a property_name does not exist in _entry._property.name. 
 I have already done a query where I find all the entries where _property.name does exist in _entry

```
List<string> filters_search_results = var_xml_filters.entry
  .SelectMany(m => m.property
    .Where(w => w.name == find_property_name), (m, w) => string.Join(" : ", new[] { m.id, w.value }))
  .Distinct()
  .OrderBy(o => o)
  .ToList();
```

but I have no idea how to do the opposite, as I cannot use !Contains as this will bring back all the properties of all the entries that are not equal to the parameter find_property_name; find_property_name is of type property_name enum.  If I don't do the ToString() cast on w.name I don't have access to Contains() at all because property_name does not contain a definition for Contains(), and if I do the cast ToString() as below, it returns all the properties

```
List<string> filters_search_results= var_xml_filters.entry
  .SelectMany(m => m.property.Where(w => !w.name.ToString().Contains(find_property_name.ToString())), (m, w) => string.Join(" : ", new[] { m.id  , "no value" }))
  .Distinct()
  .OrderBy(o => o)
  .ToList();
```

**So to clarify my question:**

If I have

```
property_name find_property_name = property_name.from;
```

I only want _entry.id if none of List<_property> name contains find_property_name.

I am stumped at how to do this; please help.  Thanks.

**EDIT**

An XML example is (with real values removed and replaced with dummy data)

```
<cls_xml_filters>
  <title>title</title>
  <entry>
    <category>category</category>
    <id>001</id>
    <updated>2020-03-14T20:04:34Z</updated>
    <property>
      <name>label</name>
      <value>value</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>from</name>
      <value>value</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>to</name>
      <value>value</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>forward</name>
      <value>value</value>
    </property>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <category>category</category>
    <id>002</id>
    <updated>2020-03-14T20:04:34Z</updated>
    <property>
      <name>from</name>
      <value>value</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>to</name>
      <value>value</value>
    </property>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <category>category</category>
    <id>003</id>
    <updated>2020-03-14T20:04:34Z</updated>
    <property>
      <name>forward</name>
      <value>value</value>
    </property>
  </entry>
</cls_xml_filters>
```

In the sample above, I am looking to find _entry.id where none of the properties contain "label".  It should return `List<string>` with values 002 and 003, because none of the properties in those two contain any properties that are of enum label.

Comment: can you show ``var_xml_filters`` example and the expected result please?

Comment: @Sajid I have edited my question and added what you requested.  Should you need more detail please shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed litle your `query` by adding `where` filter before `SelectMany`, like the following code:
`property_name find_property_name = property_name.label;`

1 - Result will be like: **id : value**

```
List<string> filters_search_results2 = var_xml_filters.entry
    .Where(m => !m.property.Select(p => p.name).Contains(find_property_name.ToString()))
    .SelectMany(m => m.property, (m, w) => $"{m.id} : {w.value}")
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(o => o)
    .ToList();
```

**Demo*

```
foreach(string item in filters_search_results2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

**Outcome**

```
002 : value
003 : value
```

2 - Result will be like: **id**

```
List<string> filters_search_results3 = var_xml_filters.entry
    .Where(m => !m.property.Select(p => p.name).Contains(find_property_name.ToString()))
    .SelectMany(m => m.property, (m, w) => $"{m.id}")
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(o => o)
    .ToList();
```

**Demo**

```
foreach(string item in filters_search_results3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

**Outcome**

```
002
003
```

Note that, i changed the `name` type to `string` of `_property` class.

I hope this will help you fix the issue.

Comment: thanks, you always come to the party when LINQ is involved, I might as well mail you directly :) I made slight changes to your query, but you were right there. The final output is `List<string> filters_search_results = var_xml_filters.entry.Where(w => !w.property.Select(s => s.name.ToString()).Contains(find_property_name.ToString())).SelectMany(m => m.property, (m, w) => string.Join(" : ", new[] { m.id, "no value" })).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o).ToList();`